# Best way of passing XML in MVC1 to a xslt

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller, xslt

in a C# project written with MVC1 I have to retrieve a XML message, add some nodes to it and then with the new XML generated display the data using xslt.

I could do it just creating a method in the controller which displays the view, and in this one I retrieve and modify the XML which is used in the xslt code. But I wonder if there's a way of creating the XML in the controller and pass it to the view?

Thanks!!

Comment: I came across a solution for displaying the xml as a result (via Content) but then, how could I apply the style in order not to display just the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XSL transformation can create html from XML, allowing you to add any nodes you like.
So if your view allows for html then I suggest you do exactly that.
You can import XML and apply XSLT with some C# statements, and then have a browser show the resulting html, I suppose.

Comment: Could I pass the xml created in the controller as a string to the view and then apply the style xslt there? Is this possible and in case it is, is a good idea?

Comment: Yes, you can have the browser apply the xslt also. Just add a line `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="yourTransformation.xslt"?>` above the XML and then open the XML in the browser.

Comment: Yep, thanks a lot Maestro!!! I've eventually added this line with xmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction and although it added the line at the bottom (for the moment, maybe I can change it) it seems to work!!